# Показ Snaсkbar при открытии Activity

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
public void onClick (View v) {
    snackbar.make(view , "salam" , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
}
```

`view` определён в параметрах. Но если я хочу просто при открытие активити вывести snackbar, то как достать view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же как-то инициализируете `view`, вероятно в `onCreate()`. Ну вот после этого и показывайте ваш Snackbar. Например:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View view = findViewById(R.id.some_view);
    Snackbar.make(view, "salam", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ...
}
```

Comment: View элемент это который главный в xml?

Comment: Да. Корневой элемент лейаута.

Comment: спасибо за помощь